# How to enumerate values and determine which is the correct scenario of a enum

Tags: c#, enums

I could be using enum the wrong way but this is my premise.  I basically have a set of 3 strings that could come in any order.  And what i'm trying to do is pick my enum that matches this order.  Basically I want to know which of my scenarios applies to the string that came in.

I've been working on a test application just to pick the correct `Possibility`.  Perhaps the code below will make more sense.  The foreach loops below also might not be the best way of doing it.  In the below code you can see I have `{ "Cow", "Chicken", "Egg" };`  I want to match this to the enum `Scenario2`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace EnumEnumerables
{
class Program
{

    enum Possibilitys
    {
        Scenario1 = Options.Chicken + Options.Cow + Options.Egg,
        Scenario2 = Options.Cow + Options.Chicken + Options.Egg,
        Scenario3 = Options.Egg + Options.Cow + Options.Chicken
    }

    enum Options
    {
        Chicken,
        Cow,
        Egg

    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //this should result in scenario 1
        //string[] myOrderofHistory = { "Chicken", "Cow", "Egg" };

        //this should result in scenario 2
        string[] myOrderofHistory = { "Cow", "Chicken", "Egg" };

        foreach (string history in myOrderofHistory)
        {
            foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Possibilitys)))
            {
                if (value == history)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,3}     0x{0:X8}     {1}",
                       (int)value, ((Possibilitys)value));
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't think this is gonna be possible in any way since there is no way to get in which orders enums are set in the Scenarios.

Comment: Your three enumerations in `Possibilitys` share the same value so it's just incorrect (`Options.Chicken + Options.Cow + Options.Egg` is the same as `Options.Egg + Options.Cow + Options.Chicken`)

Comment: All scenarios have the same value - 1 + 2 + 3 = 6. BTW, there is no question in your description. Please, specify what exactly you want to be answered.

Comment: @t3z I guess my question is how to create a collection and enumerate and pick the Possibility as listed above

Comment: Why not just have different string arrays (an array of arrays or a hashset of arrays if you want) and just compare their members with the input? I doubt you'll get a good answer unless you expose the **real** problem

Comment: I could, i guess but there is hundreds of values and the problem is i'll be reading those values and scenarios via text files

Comment: As I said, no good answer can be given without knowing the scope of the problem. I'd take a look at this: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: That said, if this answers your question, an enum *by itself* is not a good way of storing the order of anything.

Answer (score 1):

I would never recommend using Enums like this but by creating a [Flags] Enum and using the left shift operator << you can do this:

```
class Program
{
    [Flags]
    enum Options
    {
        None = 0,
        Chicken = 1,
        Cow = 2,
        Egg = 4,
    }

    enum Possibilities
    {
        Order1 = (Options.Chicken << 4) + (Options.Cow << 2) + Options.Egg,
        Order2 = (Options.Cow << 4) + (Options.Chicken << 2) + Options.Egg,
        Order3 = (Options.Egg << 4) + (Options.Cow << 2) + Options.Chicken,
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //this should result in scenario 1
        //string[] myOrderofHistory = { "Chicken", "Cow", "Egg" };

        //this should result in scenario 2
        string[] myOrderofHistory = { "Cow", "Chicken", "Egg" };
        int[] shiftValue = new int[] { 4, 2, 0 };

        int shiftIndex = 0;
        int possibility = 0;
        foreach (string history in myOrderofHistory)
        {
            Options options = (Options)Enum.Parse(typeof(Options), history);

            possibility += ((int)options) << shiftValue[shiftIndex];

            shiftIndex++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(((Possibilities)possibility).ToString());

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but in your example, the `[Flags]` attribute doesn't really serve any purpose... you are using your enum values as integers always, not as flags.

Comment: Yes I guess here I don't need to use powers of 2 for the Options enum.  But again this code/approach should never be used.  I just came up with it because it was a interesting problem...